# Frequent heavy CPU load from firefox browser -> malware?

Tags: malware, web-browser, firefox, debian, cpu

Since recently I started to get very heavy CPU load on my 64bit Debian 9.0 Cinnamon machine. I have all my packages up to date including Firefox-ESR. Often the load is so heavy that I can hear my CPU.

I also get it when restarting the browser in safe-mode. I did not get CPU load spikes before restoring my session for the time I tried.

I also did a ClamAV scan like so: `clamscan -r --bell -i --exclude-dir="^/sys" / -l clamav1.log` which tells me infected files are 0. And [rkhunter also tells me that there are no rootkits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373718/rkhunter-gives-me-a-warning-for-usr-bin-lwp-request-what-should-i-do-debi).

**Early screenshot of system monitor (also I don't know how listening to soundcloud & youtube can upload so much data but that's another question I guess?):**
[image: Early screenshot of system monitor (also I don't know how listening to soundcloud & youtube can upload so much data but that's another question I guess?)]
**When I open about:performance to check what causes the load that very tab 'seems to be it' (note the CPU usage percentage):**
[image: When I open about:performance to check what causes the load that very tab 'seems to be it' (note the CPU usage percentage)]
**In safe mode:**
[image: In safe mode]

I also get this when having just one tab open. Could tabs that aren't even loaded be causing this? Any ideas what might cause this or any suggestions for things that I could try? Note that I'm relatively new to Linux/Debian; also I'm not that sure if this would fit better into unix.stackexchange.

Comment: Video is one of the most bandwidth intensive work your typical computer would do. Especially if you set your quality to HD, it's easy to rake up gigabytes. Most CPU/GPU has video decoder accelerator though, so playing the video itself shouldn't be compute intensive.

Comment: @LieRyan Thanks; that might be the cause of the ~200MB upload over a day or so. But it's certainly not the cause for the heavy CPU load as I didn't have any tab with video open. In the bottom screenshot I have only one tab (no video) aside of about:performance opened.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware or troubleshooting forum. The best suggestion we can give is to reinstall firefox and install extensions one at a time and see the performance stats at each stage,

Comment: Probably is malware--where malware is defined as including any active adobe product/plugin.